# Error "Unresolved inclusion" while buidling Blackberry app

Tags: c++, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-10, qt5.3

Trying to build BlackBerry 10 app . Some of its parts already has been done.I have downloaded ECLIPSE indigo, QT5.31, Blackberry SDK. Now i  am trying to open it in Eclipse. But getting error :

Unresolved inclusion on following lines :

```
<bb/cascades/Application>

#include <Qt/5.3/qdeclarativedebug.h>
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/LocaleHandler>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <bb/cascades/LocaleHandler>
#include <bb/cascades/NavigationPane>
#include <bb/cascades/TabbedPane>

#include <bb/system/InvokeManager>
#include <bb/system/InvokeRequest>
#include <bb/system/InvokeTarget>
#include <bb/system/InvokeTargetReply>

#include <bb/device/DisplayInfo>
```

Project has following files with 
.CPP
.HPP
.QML
.PRO
.UI
extension.

Thanks

.PRO file  has following code :

```
APP_NAME = Gazzet

CONFIG += qt warn_on cascades10

include(config.pri)


LIBS += -lbb -lbbdevice -lbbdata -lbbsystem -lbbplatform -lbbplatformbbm
```

Comment: You have most probably forgot to add some things in .pro file. Show what's in there as well

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if thats the correct soluton but

I downloaded Momentics IDE with Blackberry 10 SDK and those errors where gone.

Thanks